# Notification is sent to mobile after log out from google account, even if logging with another account

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using `FCM` to generate `notification` for my mobile app. it works good, but when I log out from account and login with another account I noticed that notification is sent which is  related to the first account .
 How can I solve this obstacle??
I am using google sign in
sendTotopic
Messaging service

```
 public class FirebaseMessagingService extends 
 com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
 public static final String TOKEN_BROADCAST = "mytokenbroadcast";
 @Override
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
 //____ID _____
 int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
 //_____NOTIFICATION ID'S FROM FCF_____
 String messageTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
 String messageBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
 String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
 String companyposition = remoteMessage.getData().get("id");
 //String dataFrom=remoteMessage.getData().get("fromuserid");
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
     new NotificationCompat
    .Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.m)
   .setContentTitle(messageTitle).setContentText(messageBody);
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(click_action);
 resultIntent.putExtra("CompanyPosition", companyposition);
 // resultIntent.putExtra("fromuserid",dataFrom);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent =
     PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
 //____FOR OREO AND HIGHER VERSIONS_____
 if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ) {
      int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
      String channelID = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;
      NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel
     (getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id), 
  BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, importance);
      channel.setDescription(channelID);
      NotificationManager notificationManager = 
  getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
      //assert notificationManager != null;
      notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
 }
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
 getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 assert notificationManager != null;
 notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
 }
 @Override
 public void onNewToken(String s) {
 super.onNewToken(s);
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
     .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult)
      {
      String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
      storeToken(newToken);
      }
 });
 }
 private void storeToken(String token) {
 SharedPrefManager.getmInstance(getApplicationContext()).storeToken(token); 
  }}
```

this is my login form

Comment: FCM Push notification linked with device, not account. You should manage it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

When you send a device token from the client to your server, it's identifying the hardware device itself, not an authenticated user.  It's similar with topic messaging - when you send a message to a topic, the device decides whether or not to receive those messages, and it has nothing to do with the login state of the end user.

If you want to target a user for messaging, as opposed to targeted a device, you'll have to store a mapping of all the device tokens to the uid of the user.  Then, if the user wants to log out, you would have to de-associate the device's token from that UID so they no longer receive messages.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below 2 steps for handling this case effectively

1. While doing logout make an api call and clear the **Device Token** in your local server so that i won't send the notification.. Notifications are being sent based on Device Token only.
2. When a new user trying to login to app identify in the local server weather the Device Token in already available or not. If it is available make it as **NULL** and insert the token corresponding to the new logged in user